# The programmed cant find my file

Tags: visual-c++

I was doing a programmed that require me to prepare two separate input file which was name group1.txt and group2.txt and then create a programmed that finds the average score for each group

I wrote this but it cant find my file for reasons I do not know 
some help maybe thanks !

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
  string line;
  const int num_lines = 10; //change numline to any number you like, its to set the       size of the array
  string sub_code[num_lines];
  float avrgs[num_lines];
  string sub_code2[num_lines];
  float avrgs2[num_lines];
  ifstream myfile ("group1.txt");
  int sum=0,score=0,j=1,i=0,i2=0;
  double ave=0.0;


  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile>>line )
    {
    //cout<<line<<endl;
    sub_code[i] = line;
     while ( myfile>>score && score <100 && score >= 0)
    {
    sum += score;
     j++;
    }
    ave = sum/j;
    j=1;
    sum = 0;
    avrgs[i]=ave;
    i++;
     }
  }
   else
   {cout << "Unable to open file"<<endl;}
myfile.close();

//this is for the secode line
ifstream myfile2 ("group2.txt");
if (myfile2.is_open())
 {
    while ( myfile2>>line )
    {
    //cout<<line<<endl;
    sub_code2[i2] = line; //add all the subject code into the array to store sub codes
    while ( myfile2>>score && score <100 && score >= 0) //well basically the score    should be between 0 - 100,
    {                                                   //so -999 wont be read. Can      change to while ( myfile2>>score && score!=-999)
sum += score;                                       //read each grade and add it to sum
j++;                                                //just to know how many grades are there so that division can be done
}
ave = sum/j;                                        //find the average.
j=1;                                                //set j back to 1, cause j is used to count the number of marks.
sum = 0;                                            //since its sum+=score, we need to set sum back to 0, or else it will be adding on to the old marks
avrgs2[i2]=ave;                                     //add that calculated ave into the array for average
i2++;                                               //i2 is to basically know how many entries are in the file for grp2
}
  }
      else
      {cout << "Unable to open file"<<endl;}
    myfile2.close();

int gr1,gr2;
//outputing the averages and so on...
for (gr1=0;gr1<i;gr1++)
{
for(gr2=0;gr2<i2;gr2++)
{
    if(sub_code[gr1]==sub_code2[gr2]) // compare subject id before displaying
    {
    cout<<sub_code[gr1]<<"\t"<<" 1 "<<avrgs[gr1]<<endl;
    cout<<sub_code2[gr2]<<"\t"<<" 2 "<<avrgs2[gr2]<<endl;
    break;
    }
}
}
//
cout<<endl;

double grpave1=0,grpave2=0;
//to find the average of each group
for (gr1=0;gr1<i;gr1++)
{
grpave1+=avrgs[gr1];
}
for(gr2=0;gr2<i2;gr2++)
{
grpave2+=avrgs2[gr2];
}
grpave1=grpave1/i;
grpave2=grpave2/i2;
cout<<"Average for group 1:"<<grpave1<<endl;
cout<<"Average for group 2:"<<grpave2<<endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Just need to know how to get my file ! I have put in Desktop, MY document, Projects, With the C++ file and I have no idea how !! Somemore I need to have a soft copy which I dun know whether it will be able to find my file in there !

Answer (score 0):

The way you specify the file name, as "group1.txt" the file will only be found by the program if it's in the current working directory of the compiled program.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

- actually copy the file to the working directory of the program.  In many cases that will be the directory the executable resides in.
- use an absolute filename, like ("c:\Users\youruser\Desktop\group1.txt" for a file stored on the desktop on a Win7 system.